# Get node last position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, position, skshapenode

It's the third time I'm looking for help in this question. 
I have a class name `BallNode` of kind `SKShapeNode`. Inside my code I also have a function the spawn ball every 3 second from the top side of the screen. Now, I want to set a function that locate the ball position every 1 second, and so, if the `ball.position.y > 200` to print a message to the console.

The purpose of this is that if any ball will be at this position (not while it's falling down) the I will call another function. I tried to do it via `SKAction`, `update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval)`, `Timer` but I didn't succeed and I really have no idea what to do...

update - my current code:

```
var timeType1: CFTimeInterval = 0.0
var timeType2: CFTimeInterval = 2.0

override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if (currentTime - timeType1 > timeType2){
        print("time")
        self.checkBallsPosition()
        self.timeType1 = currentTime
    }
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "color.BallNode") { node, _ in
        self.checkBallsPosition()
    }
}

    func checkBallsPosition() {
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "BALL") { (node: SKNode, nil) in
        let x = self.createTopBorder()
        x.isHidden = true
        let wait2 = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
        let action2 = SKAction.run {
        let position = Double(node.position.y)
        if position < 200 {

        }
        else if position > 200 {
            print("bolbo")
            node.removeFromParent()
        }
        }
        self.run(SKAction.sequence([wait2,action2]))

        }
}
```

thats what I try do to so far, as I said the problem is that I want to get the ball **last** position. because the ball fall down the screen the last position should be when it touch the bottom border of the screen or when it touches another ball. if I set it at `update` I get the ball position every frame or (as I did) every second - but not the last. another problem is that the ball position can always change depends on another balls (when collision occurs).

update #2 - another functions:

```
    func spawnBalls() {
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3)
    let action = SKAction.run {
        self.createBall()
    }
    run(SKAction.repeatForever((SKAction.sequence([wait, action]))))
}

func createBall(){
    let ball = BallNode(radius: 65)
    print(ball.Name)
    print(ball._subName!)

    ball.position.y = ((frame.size.height) - 200)
    let ballXPosition = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))
    ball.position.x = CGFloat(ballXPosition)
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball
    ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.topBorder
    ball.delegate = self
    addChild(ball)

}
```

Comment: Post your code so we can see what is going wrong, you should be able to easily check this in `update`

Comment: just update my question, can you help me to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the entire code you are using. Not knowing how you are spawning your balls, how is the hierarchy and how you are moving them, I can't reproduce it here.

I am not sure if I understand it right, but I believe it might be simpler than what you are doing. See if the code below helps you, I am making the balls fall with `SKAction` (you can do it with physics also), and checking when they go below zero, when I remove them.

```
private let ballSpeed : CGFloat = 400
private let ballRadius : CGFloat = 10

private func spawnBall(atPoint pos : CGPoint){
    let b = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: ballRadius)
    b.name = "ball"
    b.position = pos
    addChild(b)
    b.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: -size.height, duration: TimeInterval((pos.y+size.height)/400)))
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    super.update(currentTime)
    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "ball") { (node, _) in
        if node.position.y < 0 {
            node.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        let pos = touch.location(in: self)
        spawnBall(atPoint: pos)
    }
}
```

Comment: its not what im looking for... in your code every time the ball goes down below 0 then it remove from the scene. what I want to do is that every time the ball in position y>400 then a new node will appear on the screen. the problem is that the balls fall down which mean that every ball that fall (and before it ending its fall - by touching the bottom or another ball) this node will appear. I want this node to appear only after the ball finish its physics properties and still its position is y > 500. in your code it will happened at every spawn ball without get its last position.

Comment: just update my question that it include my createBall and spawnBall function.. take a look and maybe you understand my question better...

Comment: hi, @PietroPepe - do you have any idea?

Comment: Hi, your text is not clear. "only after the ball finish its physics properties". What do you mean by "finish its physics properties"?

Comment: So you want, for every ball, to spawn a new one only at the first time it interacts with something (bottom border or another ball)?

Comment: I might take a while to answer what you say next, so I'll already give you a suggestion, if all you want for now is to detect the last interaction position:
 
- Create in `BallNode` class a `lastPosition` variable.

- Detect contact between balls and border using `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` and the callback function `didBegin`. That's when you should set the `lastPosition` value.

Comment: sorry, bit its not what I mean. it suppose to be a game that the player has to blow up the fallen balls. the game over when a ball will touch the top border of the screen. I want to detect the last position of each ball so I can alert the user when the balls are too close to the top border. hope now its more clear so you can help me better :)